# Add a Document_Open vba script to document when created from a template?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a template, Template.dotm, which is taken by a server and populated with data, then saved to a .doc. A user is then passed a link to this document so they can download it. I want to run a VBA script on that document when the user opens it.

Is there a way to accomplish this from within the template's vba script? The script of course runs fine if I simply double click the template to open an instance of it, but since the server saves a copy first, the script is gone by the time the user sees the document.

Comment: You can do this programatically, but it's very tricky unless you have enabled programmatic access to the VB Project in trust centre macro settings (which I wouldn't advise).

Can't you just write the code into the template so that it's there by default?

Comment: The problem with having the code on the template is that it runs when the server opens it and saves it as a .doc, which no longer has the macro. Unless there is some way of preserving the macro when the document is created that I am missing?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing how you actually have everything set up - as a last resort you could do the following: write a batch file to enable VB Project access by editing the DWORD value in the relevant reg key. Then use echo to produce a VBS file that inserts the required code into the document, then call the VBS file, delete it when finished and return the DWORD value back to it's original property. You can use `"%~1"` to reference the document in the batch file and have call the batch file from the command line after the new doc is saved, with the filename as argument #1

Comment: Admittedly a bit messy, especially if you don't have cmd knowledge - but it will get the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out since the file was stored locally to the template but was being opened over the network, Word was confused and severed the connection to the template. I now have a copy of the template in a shared network drive, which I set to the attached template in Document_New.

Not the nicest solution, but it's working and was easy to implement. Thought I'd post for anyone who finds themselves in a similar situation.